# Merge/synonym request: i18n / internationalization

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

[i18n](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n) should be merged into [internationalization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) and made a synonym.

They even have the same wiki but are still different tags. Merging them would be a good idea.

Comment: For now, I proposed a [synonym](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/internationalization/synonyms). But if there's no objection or reason not to soon, I'm sure we can speed up the process and carry out the merge.

Comment: And done. Since there were no objections, it seemed like a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Good suggestion - i18n *is* the abbreviation for internationalization.

For additional reference on the term: http://www.i18nguy.com/origini18n.html and the obligatory [wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).